# Incomplete output with while loop

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I am supposed to give this output

```
* * * * *
 * * * * *
* * * * * *
 * * * * *
```

so on and so forth 5 itirations
but it only shows the first 2 output

here's my code

```
public class itiration {

    public static void main( String args[]){

        int counter1 = 1;
        int counter2 = 1;
        int counter3 = 1;

        while(counter1<=5)
        {

                while(counter2<=5)
                {
                    System.out.print("* ");
                    System.out.print(" ");
                    counter2++;
                }

            System.out.println();

                while(counter3<=5)
                {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                    System.out.print("* ");
                    counter3++;
                }


            System.out.println();

            counter1++;
        }

    }

}
```

this is not a homework

Comment: In the output sample at the top of your question, the fourth line has six *s. Is that a typo or is it supposed to be like that?

Comment: What should the next line in your example sequence be? I'm not seeing any obvious pattern.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried stepping through this program with a debugger?

**HINT**: After the outer loop executes its first iteration, what are the values of counter2 and counter3?

Comment: Also, if this isn't homework, then what is it?  Just a self learning exercise?

Comment: OHHH THANKS! I forgot about the counter2 and counter3. :| now I learned something new. so their values doesn't reset? after counter1++ loops?

Comment: No, you need to explicitly reset the values.  The best way to see this is to step through this in a debugger.

Comment: This is a just a self learning exercise, since I am currently studying java. for this coming semester and I bored to death this vacation so I decided to sefl study java I am using a book. also. how do I use the debugger?

Comment: Write Java in an IDE like Eclipse or launch jdb

Comment: after that I'll click debugger? what does it do?

Comment: Google search Eclipse IDE.  You'll find plenty of material.  This really is an indispensable way of knowing what your program is doing.

Answer (score 2):

You need to reset `counter2` and `counter3` in the loop (after `counter1++` for example), otherwise they'll stay at value 5 after the first run of the loop, and the inner loops will not run any more.

Answer (score 1):

You're not resetting counter2 and counter3 for each iteration of the main loop.
Try this:

```
    int counter1 = 1;
    while(counter1<=5)
    {        
        int counter2 = 1;
        int counter3 = 1;
```